# SQL pulling null when should be pulling values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had this working previously, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what happened to it where it will not display the true values of Q4 and Q5 columns.

This query is pulling survey data and all rows have null for Q4 and Q5. Q1-Q3 have their data correctly displayed.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @start as datetime2(0) = '2021-01-01'

SELECT
    MAX(IIF(metric.name = 'Q1' AND survey.sr_actual_value BETWEEN 1 AND 5, survey.sr_actual_value, NULL)) AS Q1,
    MAX(IIF(metric.name = 'Q2' AND survey.sr_actual_value BETWEEN 1 AND 5, survey.sr_actual_value, NULL)) AS Q2,
    MAX(IIF(metric.name = 'Q3' AND survey.sr_actual_value BETWEEN 1 AND 5, survey.sr_actual_value, NULL)) AS Q3,
    MAX(IIF(metric.name = 'Q4' AND survey.sr_actual_value BETWEEN 1 AND 5, survey.sr_actual_value, NULL)) AS Q4,
    MAX(IIF(metric.name = 'Q5' AND survey.sr_actual_value BETWEEN 1 AND 5, survey.sr_actual_value, NULL)) AS Q5,
    MAX(IIF(metric.name = 'Q6', survey.sr_string_value, NULL)) AS Comment,
    MAX(survey.si_taken_on) as Taken,
    MAX(ims.number) as [Number],
    MAX(ims.sys_id) as sys_id,
    MAX(tech.name) AS Tech,
    MAX(man.first_name) AS Manager,
    MAX(cust.name) AS Customer,
    CASE
    WHEN MAX(awi.queue) = 'b63d965cdbb05454586593a6f4961968' THEN 'SS'
    WHEN MAX(awi.queue) = '67e1f6cbdb9298548fd6695e1396199c' THEN 'Chat'
    ELSE NULL
    END as [Group]

FROM [v2_sn].[u_interaction_survey_reporting] as survey

LEFT JOIN v2_sn.sys_user as cust on cust.sys_id = survey.si_user
LEFT JOIN v2_sn.asmt_metric as metric on metric.sys_id = survey.sr_metric
LEFT JOIN v2_sn.interaction as ims on ims.sys_id = survey.inter_sys_id
LEFT JOIN v2_sn.sys_user as tech on tech.sys_id = ims.assigned_to
LEFT JOIN v2_sn.sys_user as man on man.sys_id = tech.manager
left join v2_sn.awa_work_item as awi on awi.document_id = ims.sys_id

WHERE survey.si_taken_on >= @start
    and metric.name in ('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4''Q5','Q6')
    and survey.si_metric_type = '1c4f20afdbc614103779a6dc139619c9'
    and awi.queue in ('b63d965cdbb05454586593a6f4961968', '67e1f6cbdb9298548fd6695e1396199c')

GROUP BY survey.si_sys_id
```

Like I said, it was working before. I have tried changing the dates to see if it was a 2021 issue, that didn't help. I confirmed that the database has the Q4 and Q5 data and that it should not be NULL. Does anyone have a clue what happened here? Any help would be appreciated. If you need further info or have questions, do not hesitate.

Comment: You are missing a comma between Q4 and Q5: `and metric.name in ('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4''Q5','Q6')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma in `and metric.name in ('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4''Q5','Q6')`. No metric name equals literal string `Q4''Q5`